# How does All Star Superman fit into continuity?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, all-star-superman

I recently read All Star Superman and the storyline seems to have quite different results that aren't reflected in the normal Superman canon.  Where does ASS fit - is it completely separate, is it a different universe (a la Marvel), or is it somehow part of the normal continuity?

Wikipedia mentions the All Star series was intended to be without the usual DC Universe restrictions, but that can cover a wide spectrum with ASS's handling of stuff like

> Krypto, black kryptonite, cloning of Superman, etc.

Comment: Lulz you said ass...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[All-Star Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-Star_Superman) does not fit into ANY DC continuity. Consider him a one-shot, never to be repeated, expression of the character of Superman. The DC Animated [feature film All-Star Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-Star_Superman_%28film%29) was based on the comic book series All-Star Superman.**

As noted in Wikipedia:

> All-Star Superman is a twelve-issue comic book series featuring Superman that ran from November 2005 to October 2008. The series was written by Grant Morrison, drawn by Frank Quitely, digitally inked by Jamie Grant and published by DC Comics. DC claimed that this series would "strip down the Man of Steel to his timeless, essential elements".
>
> The series was the second to be launched in 2005 under DC's All-Star imprint, the first being All Star Batman and Robin the Boy Wonder. **These series are attempts by DC to allow major comics creators a chance to tell stories showcasing these characters without being restricted by DC Universe continuity.** [emphasis mine]

With that said, the All Star Superman was not a single Superman but an amalgam or archetype of the iconic hero across his entire heritage encompassing all of his previous incarnations. This was done to allow a well known writer to try and expound on the legend of Superman unrestricted.

Grant Morrison used elements from across the history of the character to create a single story that embodied every Age of Superman. **All-Star Superman is not the canon character of Superman, he is the paragon of the archetype. The ultimate expression of what Superman could have been given all of the best versions of him.**